# c# speech recognition part of phrase - windows.speech

Tags: c#, speech-recognition

I am using Windows.Speech API
What I am trying to do is get the system to recognize part of a phrase rather than look for the whole thing. 
For instance, if I load the the string with: "How are you", it requires the user to say exactly, how are you. ultimately, I would like Windows.Speech to recognize something like this too: "Hey How are you today".

Here is what I currently have:

```
//This is used for Building the recognizer engine. 
Choices commands = new Choices();
commands.Add(new string[] { Question5, 
Question1,Question3,Question2,Question4});
GrammarBuilder gBuilder = new GrammarBuilder();
gBuilder.Append(commands);
Grammar grammar = new Grammar(gBuilder);

//Loading the Grammar engine
recEngine.LoadGrammarAsync(grammar);
recEngine.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();
recEngine.SpeechRecognized += recEngine_SpeechRecognized;
```

Then for display:

```
void recEngine_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Result.Text == Question1)
    {
        richTextBox1.Text += "\nYou have Asked Question 1";
        chkBoxQ1.Checked = true;
        agentScore = agentScore + 1;
        stopCussing = Response1;
        Form2 responseForm = new Form2();
        responseForm.Show();
        Question1Answer = "Question Asked";
        txtBoxAnswer1.Enabled = true;
    }
    else if (e.Result.Text == Question2)
    {
        richTextBox1.Text += "\nYou have now asked Question 2";
        chkQuestion2.Checked = true;
        stopCussing = Response2;
        Form2 responseForm = new Form2();
        responseForm.Show();
        agentScore = agentScore + 1;
        Question2Answer = "Question Asked";
        txtAnswer2.Enabled = true;
    }
    else if (e.Result.Text == Question3)
    {
        richTextBox1.Text += "\nYou have now asked Question 3";
        chkQuestion3.Checked = true;
        stopCussing = Response3;
        Form2 responseForm = new Form2();
        responseForm.Show();
        agentScore = agentScore + 1;
        Question3Answer = "Question Asked";
        txtAnswer3.Enabled = true;
    }
    else if (e.Result.Text == Question4)
    {
        richTextBox1.Text += "\nYou have now asked Question 4";
        chkQuestion4.Checked = true;
        stopCussing = Response4;
        Form2 responseForm = new Form2();
        responseForm.Show();
        agentScore = agentScore + 1;
        Question4Answer = "Question Asked";
        txtAnswer4.Enabled = true;
    }
    else if (e.Result.Text == Question5)
    {
        richTextBox1.Text += "\nYou have now asked Question 5";
        chkQuestion5.Checked = true;
        stopCussing = Response5;
        Form2 responseForm = new Form2();
        responseForm.Show();
        agentScore = agentScore + 1;
        Question5Answer = "Question Asked";
        txtAnswer5.Enabled = true;
    }
```

Any Insight here would be great! 
FYI, I have thought of using cognitive services -- But if I can make windows.speech do what I need, I'd rather not rewrite.

Comment: Have a list of possible phrases in a DB or file, then search them for the phrase said...

Comment: Hey Johnny - how can I fit that into my model? Basically I have a "manager" whom updates questions, and based off of those questions they're loaded into the builder and presented for an "agent" to ask.  Is there a way to present something to the nature of: They can ask this, but it can append or precede with these words?

Comment: I don't understand your question.  You look up the the phrase whether it contains each token (word) they say, find the one that contains the most words they said, then replace it with the phrase found

Comment: Oh oh - like a fuzzylookup if you will. Hmm let me see how I can work that out. That's not a bad Idea...

Comment: This is just an easiest way I could think of with out diving too deep into NLP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to answer my own question. The comments here were helpful, but they didn't do the trick for partials. I actually found that if you add .contains, it will accept approximates - only caveat is that the statement being said has to start with the same word. Example code below:

```
void recEngine_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.Result.Text.Contains( Question1)) //This did the trick here
        {
            richTextBox1.Text += "\nYou have Asked Question 1";
            questionCode = "Question1";
            chkBoxQ1.Checked = true;
            agentScore = agentScore + 1;
            stopCussing = Response1;
            //Form2 responseForm = new Form2();
            //responseForm.Show();
            FurtherResponse further = new FurtherResponse(questionCode, programcode);
            further.Show();
            Question1Answer = "Question Asked";
            txtBoxAnswer1.Enabled = true;
        }
        else if (e.Result.Text.Contains(Question2))
        {
            richTextBox1.Text += "\nYou have now asked Question 2"; 
            chkQuestion2.Checked = true;
            stopCussing = Response2;
            //Form2 responseForm = new Form2();
            //responseForm.Show();
            agentScore = agentScore + 1;
            Question2Answer = "Question Asked";
            txtAnswer2.Enabled = true;
            questionCode = "Question2";
            FurtherResponse further = new FurtherResponse(questionCode, programcode);
            further.Show();
        }
```